# Question about Haar Measure from Halmos

Tags: measure-theory

Halmos (Measure Theory, 1950, p. 256) poses the question: Given a Locally Compact Group $G$, compact subsets of measure zero, $C$ and $D$, is the group product, $P=CD$, which is also compact, also of measure zero?

This seems like a simple question but I am having trouble finding the key.

I have the following strategy in mind, but I am not sure it is sound, or necessary.

1. Consider the Cartesian Product $ F=G\times G $. The (group) product, $P$, may be identified with the set of equivalence classes in $F$ $$ \left\{\left(g_1,g_2\right), \left(g_3,g_4\right),...\right\} $$ defined by $ g_1g_2=g_3g_4 $
2. Give these the quotient topology? Not sure this helps.

Thanks for any guidance or a solution.

-Jones

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, there are lots of counterexamples.

Take $G=(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ with the standard 2D area measure for the group and $C = [0,1] \times \{0\}$ and $D = \{0\} \times [0,1]$ for the compact sets of measure zero. Then $P = C+D = [0,1]^2$.

I guess you could even take $G$ to be the Torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ to get an example where $G$ is a compact group...